# How to remove sink faucet pipe from shutoff?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, faucet, copper

I am currently attempting to replace the faucet in my kitchen. I successfully removed the hot water pipe that goes from the old faucet to the hot water shutoff. I am now trying to remove the cold water pipe from the cold water shutoff and I ran into a problem. I thought that when I removed the nut pictured in my thumb the pipe would just come right out from the shutoff, however only the nut came loose and it looks like the pipe from the old faucet is still inside the water shutoff valve. I have tried to pull the faucet pipe out from the shutoff but it appears to be stuck pretty bad. Every time I pull the faucet pipe, it pulls the whole water shutoff and I am afraid that if I pull too hard I'll break the sink pipe or the water shutoff pipe. Does anyone have any tips to help me remove the sink pipe from the water shutoff?

Thank you,
Justin

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a large pair of diagonal wire cutters and about 3" above the shut off valve cut the faucet riser pipe in two.  Now carefully use a pair of common pliers, jaws  clamped around the riser pipe stub, swivel the stub back and forth a few degrees, at the same time lifting and rocking.